# Enquiry, grammar correction

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Would you please tell me which of these four sentences is correct one? I am so confused with them :(

1. Action movies are three times as popular as comedies for men.
2. Action movies are three times more popular than comedies for men.
3. Men watch action movies three times as many as comedies.
4. Three times as many men watch action movies than comedies.

Answer (score 2):

**2. "Action movies are three times more popular than comedies for men"** sounds best to my ear. You might get away with using 1. (although I believe it is still incorrect), but 3. and 4. are definitely wrong. Number 2. is the only sentence of the four that makes a reasonable assertion about the watching preferences of men.

Comment: Dear Hubbard, you say "You might get away with using 1. (although I believe it is still incorrect)". So said, your point appears to be confusing. If you believe 1. is incorrect, then how come you say "You might get away with using 1. To me, both of the first two sentences are correct, each throwing a different meaning.

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg- I apologize. I should have said, "You might get away with using example 1. in informal speech, as your meaning will likely still be understood." However, "three times as popular as" is just poor usage to my ear, especially when "three times more popular than" is available as a more accurately understood alternative. Nevertheless, I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are both correct in Br English but make different assertions.

**.1.** If 100 men enjoy comedies, then three times as many is 300, so three hundred enjoy action movies, if popularity is reflected in numbers.

**.2.** If comedies are popular with 100 men then three times more popular will add three hundred watchers to that number; hence 400 will be watching action movies.

**,3,** and **.4.** need improvement, to be acceptable in Br. English. These two introduce yet more different meanings.

> .3. Men watch action movies three times as ***often*** as comedies. **or**
>   .3. Men watch  three times as many action movies as comedies.
>   .4. Three times as many men watch action movies ***as*** comedies.

So if the point is to choose correct grammar,only .1. and .2. are good.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing logic with the way people actually use English. Even on programmes on respected TV channels, 'Three times more than' is often used for 'three times as many'.

Comment: And even the logic is wrong, I'm ashamed to admit. **,2,** should state  "If comedies are.. 400 will be watching action movies." But the final sentence is to the point.

Comment: Dear Hugh, you are absolutely correct.